# Does the rules "7 or more consecutive points on one side" in Statistical Process Control take in account the amount of data point?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, quality-control

I'm reading on Control chart rules and there is a rule which says: "7 or more consecutive points on one side" in considered "out of control". However, does it take into account the amount of data points? For example, if I have 100 data points (i.e does In-process control tests 100 times), the probability of having <=6 consecutive points on one side is statistically much more higher than if I have 5000 data points (does the tests 5000 times).

In a sense, I'm thinking it's similar to coins tosses. The more times you tosses, the more likely you are getting a streak of k heads in a row. And for an expected amount of tosses you are 99% guaranteed to get 7 in a row. Or am i missing something?

I expected the rules to be like: Not more than k consecutive points on one side, and k is calculated by some formula which includes the amount of data points.

Thank you for your insight.